# Unable to fit_transform data from csv file in sklearn

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to learn some classification in Scikit-learn. However, I couldn't figure out what this error means.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data_frame = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0) 
data_in_numpy = data_frame.values 

c = CountVectorizer()
c.fit_transform(data_in_numpy.data)
```

This throws an error:

```
NotImplementedError: multi-dimensional sub-views are not implemented
```

How can I go around this issue? One record from my csv file looks like:

```
Time   Directors    Actors   Rating   Label
123    Abc, Def     A, B,c    7.2      1
```

I suppose this error is due to the fact that there are more than one values under Directors or Actors column. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docstring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer will:

> Convert a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts

So then why, I wonder, are you inputing numerical values?

Try transforming only the strings (directors and actors):

```
data_in_numpy['X'] = data_frame[['Directors', 'Actors']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
data_in_numpy = data_frame['X'].values
```

First though, you might want to clean the data up by removing the commas.

```
data_frame['Directors'] = data_frame['Directors'].str.replace(',', ' ')
data_frame['Actors'] = data_frame['Actors'].str.replace(',', ' ')
```

Comment: Now it throws an error of 

    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

While I can fit transform one one feature but can't for more than one.

    c.fit_transform(d['Writer'].values)

However, 

    c.fit_transform(d[['Actors', 'Directors']].values) 

raises an  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'.

Comment: So then the count vectorizer is expecting only one column of data. You should either do each separately or create a new df column to transform. Please see the changes I've made to my answer.